# Why won't Blender pack this image file?

Tags: image, uv-image-editor

I went to the Image Editor.  Selected this file name.  Clicked the folder icon.  Navigated to the image file.  The image file is there.
Why it still says Unable to Pack File?

Could it be because some material is using it somewhere else?
I was hoping if it was found in the Image Editor, it would be usable by all the materials referencing that image?

If not, how can I find the material which is looking for this image?  File has approximately 60 materials.

Thanks

[image]

Comment: I use Blender for creativity and don't get into it's mechanics more than I have to but I was having this problem and went to the preferences, opened System tab and increased the GLSL "Memory Cache" to 4096.  (I think it was at 1024)   After that ordinary texture images were being packed with exported Blender files, although video files were not.  I suspect because of their sheer size.  This might just solve your problem also.  I guess you'd need to have about 8 or more Gigs of memory to nominate that 4096 figure.

Comment: You mean the Sequencer/Clip Editor Memory Cache?  I increased that to 4096, but still would not pack the files.

Comment: That was what I was referring to, yes.  Must have been a coincidence for me then?  I have 16 Gigs RAM, but have always had that much in this machine.  Am curious now. Will be a good one to track down.  If I learn why, I'll drop the info here.  Would appreciate you (or anyone) doing the same.  :)

Comment: To add to the above - Since April 2016, I did change from Vers. 2.76 to 2.77a.   Is this what you're running?  I've not moved to 2.78 yet.

Comment: I'm on 2.77a.  PC has 32gb ram.

Comment: More than enough!!  lol    Haven't been trying too much to upset my installation.  In the middle of a priority video project at present which is on a deadline.  Blender has been so full of 'surprises' since I started getting into it, quite frankly , I'm not brave enough.  :o

Comment: Further to above... I've got a tiny low end laptop with Blender installed.  I'll poke around with that one soon as I get the chance.

Comment: Had to upload a blender file for another answer and guess what, the darned texture file wouldn't pack!!!!  It turned out I'd changed the filename of the image and also did the same in Blender, BUT, the slot under the image filename had the old name and it wouldn't let me edit that no matter what.  I closed Blender, deleted what was in Blender's temp (holding) folder, and went back in, and bingo, it had picked up the change automatically.  Could this be related in some way to your problem?.